# Apple Provisioning Portal Access: Allowing Team Members

Tags: ios, mobile, app-store-connect

I'm trying to allow a team member access to the provisioning portal (by creating a new user via iTunes Connect) - but it only allows them access to Connect. Trying to access the provisioning portal informs them they need to pay the $99 annual fee. Why aren't they associated to my portal (I created their account), and is there a work-around for this? Any help?

Zach

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to [Invite a Person to Your Team via the Developer Program Member Center](https://developer.apple.com/membercenter/index.action#singleinvite).

From [**Apple Developer Program Roles Overview**](https://developer.apple.com/programs/roles/index.php):

> There are three possible roles that can be assigned to Apple Developer
>   Program members: Agent, Admin, or Member. Developer Program roles are
>   used to assign certain responsibilities to a developer, such as
>   accepting Program Agreements, inviting additional team members, and
>   creating and approving digital certificates. The Admin and Member
>   roles are only available to developers enrolled as a company in the
>   iOS, Mac, or Safari Developer Program.
>
> - **Agent**
>     The Agent (the original enrollee accepted into an Apple Developer Program) is the primary contact for the development team, is
>     responsible for accepting all Developer Program Agreements, and can
>     enroll their team in additional Apple Developer Programs.
> - **Admin** (company only)
>     Developers assigned the Admin role serve as a secondary contact for teams enrolled in an Apple Developer Program as
>     a company. Team Admins can invite members to the team, assign roles,
>     and have access to the resources and benefits of the developer program
>     they are enrolled in.
> - **Member** (company only)
>     Developers assigned the Member role have access to the resources and benefits of the developer program they are
>     enrolled in.
>
> Developers can also be assigned “No Access”. This designation prohibits the access to any program benefits for a specific Program,
>   allowing an Agent or Admin to delineate responsibilities and access to
>   resources for their team members between Developer Programs.